# Cannot Connect to Subversion (SVN) on AWS

Tags: svn, amazon-web-services, repository

I've got an AWS server setup with multiple subdomains on it, such as:

```
demo.example.com
test.example.com
dd.example.com
```

I'm trying to set up a subversion repository on `dd.example.com` and to do so went into the `/var/www/html/dd` directory and ran a `svnadmin create ./donedone`

I then went into `/var/www/html/dd/donedone/conf/svnserve.conf` and added the following three lines to the bottom:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

I then added my credentials to the bottom of the `/var/www/html/dd/donedone/conf/passwd` file:

```
joe = passw0rd
```

I created a log file `/var/www/html/dd/svn.log` and set the permissions to `777` then ran the `svnserve` command as so:

```
svnserve -d -r /var/www/html/dd/donedone/ --log-file /var/www/html/dd/svn.log
```

Doing a `ps -ef | grep svnserve` **does** show it is running, but when I try to check out the repository from my local machine using TortiseSVN or PhpStorm it says it cannot connect to repository (never even getting to the point of asking me for credentials).

I've tried with the following endpoints, but never with any luck:

```
svn://dd.example.com
svn://dd.example.com/donedone
svn://ec2-54-165-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
svn://ec2-54-165-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/donedone
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but cannot figure out what it is.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SVN protocol (not HTTP), then have you made sure that the security group you have assigned on that EC2 instance is letting traffic in on port 3690? (or other port if you have changed it)

This post may help: http://mengtang.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/how-to-set-up-svn-repository-with-amazon-aws/